# Find all polynomials with $h(0) = h(1)$, $h'(0) = h'(1)$ and $h''(0) = h''(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, dynamical-systems

I am trying to construct a $C^2$ map from $h:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  At first I came up with

$$h(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} x(1-x) & x \in [0,1]\\
h(x - n) & x \in [n,n+1] , n \in \mathbb{Z}\end{array} \right. $$

The problem with such a function is that it has different left and right derivaives at $x = 0$:

$$ h''(0^-) = -2 \text{ but } h''(0^+) = 2 $$

Perhaps we could try a more systematic approach.  We could use a piecewise polynomial function with:

- $h\;\,(0) = h \,\;(1)$
- $h'\,(0) = h'\,(1)$
- $h''(0) = h''(1)$

The space of polynomials with of degree of a certain degree is $\deg h + 1$.  Then if we impose three relations like these the dimension is:

$$ \dim V = (\deg h + 1) - 3 = \deg h - 2$$

So it should come surprise that the only quadratic equation satisfying these differential constraints.

---

I considered the possibility $ h(x) = x^2 (1 - x)^2 $ and it looks like it works:

$$h''(x) = 2x + 2(1-x) + 8x(1-x) = h''(1-x)$$

There are two possibilities for the general solution:

- $p\big( x(1-x) \big)$ for certain polynomials
- $x^2 (1-x^2)\,p(x)$ for certain polynomials

Comment: Does it need to be piecemeal polynomial? Would something like $h (x)=\sin (2\pi x)$ do? Also, what about $h (x)=x$, which is well defined on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ because, if $x-y\in\mathbb Z$, $h(x)-h(y)\in\mathbb Z $

Comment: why don't you try $$h(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$$?

Comment: @user8734617 I believe $z \mapsto f(z)/|f(z)|$ works with $z=r\,e^{i\theta}$. Maybe I don't want to use Fourier series at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you write $h = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$, the three conditions become

$$\sum_1^n a_k = 0, \quad \sum_2^n ka_k = 0, \quad \sum_3^nk(k-1)a_k = 0$$

So, the coefficients from $a_4$ to $a_n$ are arbitrary, and the equations give unique solutions for $a_1, a_2, a_3$. $a_0$ is also arbitrary. In particular, the only CUBIC polynomials that satisfy your conditions are constants.

From here, it is not clear what you are asking. Do you want the set of solution written "in closed form", perhaps as the set of multiples of some polynomial, or as polynomials in a fixed polynomial? What are you looking for?

Comment: Hmm... You have found 3 equations in $n$ unknowns. So maybe I'd like a basis for the null space of the corresponding $3 \times n$ matrix. $$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc} 1&1&1&\dots&1 \\ 0&1&2&\dots& n \\ 0&0&2&\dots&n(n-1)\end{array}\right]$$ These become polynomials that generate the solution space to $h(0)=h(1)$, $h'(0)=h'(1)$ ,$h''(0)=h''(1)$ in polynomials of degree $\deg h = n$.

Comment: Wait your system of equations is almost correct. We should have $h(0)=a_0 =\sum a_n $, $h'(0)=a_1= \sum n a_n $ and $h''(0)=2a_2= \sum n(n-1)a_n$.  You can let $0 \leq k \leq n$ and... That's exactly what you've got. My matrix should then be $$\left[ \begin{array}{ccccccc} 0&1&1&1&\dots&1 \\ 0&0&1&2&\dots& n \\ 0&0&0&2&\dots&n(n-1)\end{array}\right]$$ So there is the constant function $p(x)\equiv 1$ and then a quartic $p(x)=x^2(1-x)^2$. I wonder if there are any solutions such that $p(x)\neq p(1-x)$?